# Convert XML item to hyperlink using XSL

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Here is the XML that is bein processed

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<javancss>
    <sourceFile name="D:\EM_Projects\javancssParser\src\old_code_complexity.xml"/>
    <compareFile name="D:\EM_Projects\javancssParser\src\new_code_complexity.xml"/>
    <summaryFile name="D:\EM_Projects\javancssParser\src\Summary.xml"/>
    <packages />
    <functions />
    <objects />
</javancss>
```

And here is a snippet of the XSLT  to go alongwith it

```
<center><table border="1" cellspacing="5">
<tr>
<th>File</th>
<th>Path</th>
<th>Link </th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>sourceFile</td>
<td> <a> <xsl:value-of select="/javancss/sourceFile/@name" /> </a></td>
<td>  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>compareFile </td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="/javancss/compareFile/@name" /> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>compareFile </td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="/javancss/compareFile/@name" /> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>

</table>
</center>
```

What I want to do is to take the Path ( represented by 2nd column in each row ) and place a hyperlink to it in the 3rd column ( in the respective `<td> </td>` , which are blank for now) . What is the way to go about the same ?

All inputs will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <center>
            <table border="1" cellspacing="5">
                <tr>
                    <th>File</th>
                    <th>Path</th>
                    <th>Link </th>
                </tr>

                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </table>
        </center>       

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="javancss">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="link-row" select="sourceFile"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="link-row" select="compareFile"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="link-row" select="summaryFile"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="link-row">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></td>
            <td>
                <a href="{@name}">link</a>
            </td>
        </tr>       
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

applied on the given input document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<javancss>
    <sourceFile name="D:\EM_Projects\javancssParser\src\old_code_complexity.xml"/>
    <compareFile name="D:\EM_Projects\javancssParser\src\new_code_complexity.xml"/>
    <summaryFile name="D:\EM_Projects\javancssParser\src\Summary.xml"/>
    <packages />
    <functions />
    <objects />
</javancss>
```

produces the following output

```
<center>
    <table border="1" cellspacing="5">
        <tr>
            <th>File</th>
            <th>Path</th>
            <th>Link </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>sourceFile</td>
            <td>D:\EM_Projects\javancssParser\src\old_code_complexity.xml</td>
            <td>
                <a href="D:\EM_Projects\javancssParser\src\old_code_complexity.xml">link</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>compareFile</td>
            <td>D:\EM_Projects\javancssParser\src\new_code_complexity.xml</td>
            <td>
                <a href="D:\EM_Projects\javancssParser\src\new_code_complexity.xml">link</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>summaryFile</td>
            <td>D:\EM_Projects\javancssParser\src\Summary.xml</td>
            <td>
                <a href="D:\EM_Projects\javancssParser\src\Summary.xml">link</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</center>
```

Note that:

- You probably don't want your table header in the same template that is used for the data rows
- Setting the context to the node of interest makes your XPath expressions shorter and more readable
- You probably meant summaryFile for the last item